# Does a Gambian need a visa to transit Amsterdam?

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, ams, klm, gambian-citizens

I am a Gambian, traveling from Malaysia to Dakar, Senegal via Amsterdam and Istanbul. Do I need a transit visa for Amsterdam if the connection time is less than 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can probably transit without a visa.

A [Timatic search using the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/hk/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=GM&NV=Gambia&DC=SN&DV=Senegal&TC=NL%2cTR&TV=Netherlands%2cTurkey&h=5ecad8627ffec6b016ce9032e03cc77b9fdbb2) says:

> Transit - Netherlands (NL)
>
> Visa
>   Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Holders of onward tickets transiting by the same or first connecting aircraft:

So unless your transit time exceeds 24 hours, you don't need a visa.

BTW, you didn't ask about Turkey, but you can transit there without visa if the transit time is less than 24 hours.

Comment: The question is for **Gambia** not **Ghana**.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLazarus for the important correction. Edited (reversing the answer).

Comment: Downvote replaced with upvote after correction

Comment: @busuraboy, if the answer is useful, please accept it.